# Getting an iterator to a const map<char, int>

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

So, I am trying to get an iterator to a map that I am passing in as a const reference to a function. My compiler complains when I do something like this:

```
bool func(string s, const map<char, int>& m){
    std::map<char, int>::iterator it = m.begin();
    /*more code here...*/
}
```

How should I do this?

The error message is:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'const_iterator' (aka '__map_const_iterator<typename __base::const_iterator>') to 'std::map<char, int>::iterator'
  (aka '__map_iterator<typename __base::iterator>')
    std::map<char, int>::iterator it = m.begin();
```

Comment: `auto it = m.begin();` done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is `m` is `const` so `m.begin()` returns a `const_iterator` not an `iterator`.  You either need to use:

```
std::map<char, int>::const_iterator it = m.begin();
```

Or for simplicity use `auto` and you have:

```
auto it = m.begin();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `const_iterator` instead:

```
std::map<char, int>::const_iterator it = m.begin();
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. So, if I were allowed to use a regular iterator would the regular iterator be allowed to edit the map whereas the const_iterator knows it's not allowed to edit the map?

Comment: @K.Shores [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527686/how-to-update-stdmap-after-using-the-find-method)

Comment: @K.Shores yes that exact reason why there is regular `iterator` and `const_iterator` for `std::map`