# Why does this update to a map in a vector<map<int, int>> fail?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I have a data structure represented by a vector of maps, all of which have the same template type. Inserting and reading works fine - however, for some reason, updates do nothing. I tried the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527686/how-to-update-stdmap-after-using-the-find-method), and they work fine - if I just use the map itself. However, when the map is in the vector, the element is found but not updated. Below, I have provided a minimal example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>

std::vector<std::map<int, int>> vec = std::vector<std::map<int, int>>();

void insert_or_update( int key, int value ) {
    for ( std::map<int, int> map: vec ) {
        auto location = map.find( key );
        if ( location != map.end()) {
            location->second = value;
            std::cout << "This should update the value, but doesn't" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Insert, if no map currently contains the key
    std::cout << "This value is new" << std::endl;
    vec.back().insert( {key, value} );
}

int get_key( int key ) {
    for ( std::map<int, int> map: vec ) {
        auto location = map.find( key );
        if ( location != map.end()) {
            return location->second;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "This value doesn't exist yet" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   std::map<int, int> map = std::map<int, int>();
   vec.push_back( map ); 
   std::cout << get_key(3) << std::endl;
   insert_or_update(3, 3);
   std::cout << get_key(3) << std::endl;
   insert_or_update(3, 5);
   std::cout << get_key(3) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Update in list failed, do it manually..." << std::endl;
   auto location = map.find( 3 );
   location->second = 5;
   std::cout << location->second << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Why does this fail? I'm sure it's some kind of pointer logic I don't understand.
2. What do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: In `for ( std::map<int, int> map: vec ) { ` you are iterating over copies of maps. Replace that with  `for ( std::map<int, int>& map: vec ) { `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this line:

```
for ( std::map<int, int> map: vec ) {
```

Is enumerating over every element in `vec` **by value**.  It's making **a copy** of the map on each iteration of the for loop.  Hence, you are inserting a new value into the copy and not the into item that's actually in the vector.  This is likely what you want - enumerate the items **by reference**:

```
for ( std::map<int, int>& map: vec ) {
```

Or simply:

```
for ( auto& map: vec ) {
```

Do the same for the same line in `get_key`

Answer (score 3):

Your function `insert_or_update` makes a copy of `vec` in the `for` loop:

```
for ( std::map<int, int> map: vec ) {
    auto location = map.find( key );
    if ( location != map.end()) {
        location->second = value;
        std::cout << "This should update the value, but doesn't" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

If you want to change the `vec` you need a reference instead of a copy:

```
for ( std::map<int, int> & map: vec ) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Ah, this makes perfect sense. I still have to get a better grasp on C++. Thanks!